# Any suggestions on how I can fix this hair issue or "crop" it out and get away with it?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, blending

I'm having another challenging "hair day".

I have an image I would like to sharpen and remove the feathering around the hair. It does not look professional at all.

Any suggestions on how I can either trim it away nicely or remove the feathering?

(image below)

[image]

Comment: Is that two layers with the green a new background you added in or is that a flat layer?

Comment: It is two layers